# How to make a concatenated label appear on different lines in Tableau Crosstab

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I'm trying to to make a concatenated label appear on different lines in Tableau Crosstab.
I made this calculation `[X Label] + CHAR(10) + [Y Label] + CHAR(10) + [Z Label]`

[image]

Now when I download the crosstab, the data looks like this:
[image]

***I want the XYZ Label column to appear on different rows like that in tableau.***

Here's the data for reference:

[image]

Here's the Tableau Public Link to the dashboard [Click here](https://public.tableau.com/views/Book1_16826822250980/Dashboard1?:language=en-US&publish=yes&:display_count=n&:origin=viz_share_link)

Any help would be most highly appreciated.